# Scala akka ActorFor path

Tags: scala, akka, remote-actors

Here is my code for finding an actor on my remote system:

```
Application.system.actorFor("akka://ActorApplication@172.17.100.232:2552/home/louis/scala/remoteActor")
```

I think I have the wrong path specified.

Is this correct:

/home/louis/scala/

Is the location of the Play! project on the remote server. And then "remoteActor" is the name if the actor.

But it is never returning an ActorRef object, it is always null.

Answer (score 2):

no, the address should likely be:

```
"akka://ActorApplication@172.17.100.232:2552/user/remoteActor"
```

This assumes that `ActorApplication` is indeed the correct name for the actor system you are trying to access on :2552.  The `/user/` portion of the url indicates it is a actor you created in that system. (you being the "user")

Comment: I have two different servers and the location is different for both of them. But for both servers I should use "/user/" for the path?

Comment: should I use "/home/ryan/" instead, in red hat linux. The user name is actually "root" though. SHould I user "/root/" ?

Comment: no, it should be exactly "/user/"  this doesn't have anything to do with actual system users.

Comment: I am using red hat linux, and there is no directory named "/user/" on my server. Does that matter?

Comment: should I be using "context.actorFor", or "Application.system.actorFor" ?

Comment: @user1491739 You obviously don't know how akka works, yet. I suggest you read the documentation step by step and build a local application, before you start with a remote one.

Comment: @user1491739 if you have a context, use it.  If this still isn't working for you, please update your question to show how you created the actor you are trying to now lookup.