# Real-time java game: Socket or RMI

Tags: java, sockets, rmi, game-engine

I'm developing a game, and I thought I will add a multiplayer options. It's a real time game, like Snake or something like this, so I'm updating the sprites positions really fast:

```
while (isRunning) {
   ...
   if (sprite instanceof PlayerSprite) {
            PlayerSprite player = ((PlayerSprite) sprite);
            collisionManager.checkCollision(player, map, elapsedTime, currTime);
            updatePosition(player, elapsedTime);
            player.animeUpdate(elapsedTime);
   }
   ...
}
```

I tried first with RMI: I stored every position in an object and I made it remote. So both the server and the client can update it. But as I said it needs to update real time.
And the RMI doesn't look like it can solves this. But I'm really a beginner, so I don't know for sure.

So my question is: RMI or simple IO (socket) would be the best solution for a real time game?

If socket is better: Can I send the position-storing object via ObjectOutput/ObjectInput to the client, update the object (and draw to the screen) and then send back the updated object to the server, and so on?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is: RMI or simple IO (socket) would be the best
>   solution for a real time game?

This question is easy enough to answer. Between the two, sockets are the way to go. RMI contains a significant amount of overhead, which slows the transport time. The goal with something real-time is to reduce the time between sending and receiving information to be as short as possible.

> If socket is better: Can I send the position-storing object via
>   ObjectOutput/ObjectInput to the client, update the object (and draw to
>   the screen) and then send back the updated object to the server, and
>   so on?

You can, but as already mentioned, it is slow. You will need to either use a library that has a client-server messaging system (I use [Kryonet](https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/)) or write up your own protocol. The key thing, which may seem obvious, is that the client and server have an easy way of understanding each other.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I'll try with simple sockets first, I'm a bit familiar with it. Then I'll give a shot to Kryonet :)

Answer (score 1):

I will not suggest to use either Socket or RMI!

In my opinion you should go with REST Services to handle multi player.

Comment: Never heard about it. Can you post a tutorial? As I look its a web service, or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you're for speed, then don't use Java serialization as [it is much slower than JSON serialization](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki).

[JSON is fine](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), personally I would give a try to [Akka Remote Actors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934782/akka-2-1-minimal-remote-actor-example) which utilize Google Protocol Buffers, though it would require studying.

Comment: Correction: Akka uses ProtoBuf for the remote protocol, but the user-level messages can be serialized using whatever you want.